# I can't get 3 twitter widgets in Divs to line up next to each other?

Tags: javascript, css, html, twitter

They all go to the right spots except the 3rd widget goes under where all the others are but still on the right.

Stackoverflow wasn't being nice so I had to put the code on pastbin.

HTML
http://pastebin.com/hSLwp2u7

CSS
http://pastebin.com/k0eWm0Bn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the right code :

CSS : http://pastebin.com/B7N5uyYZ

Changes : 
   1. float doesn't have a center value ( same as lqc )
   2. margin auto is not needed for float right and left ( again same as lqc )
   3. THE IMPORTANT THING : When u set margin left and right to auto the margins cover the whole div so no other element can be rendered near . so a small math : (100 - (30*3))/2 = 5 .. So u need to give 5% of margin to the mid element to get in the center. ( correcting Hareesh.. it's not 99% . it's 100% man :D )

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
#midtweet{
    margin:0 4.5%;
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
 }
```

also remove margins from #leftweet

Answer (score 0):

`center` is not a correct value for float, so the middle one is not a float, which is why the 3rd one is rendered under the 2nd. Also "margin: auto" has absolute no meaning for floats.

You should either make the middle one float left or get rid of floats all together and [use `display: table-cell`](http://jsfiddle.net/R4QPj/14/).